# android custom round layout

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I want to make something like the image in the link, so I've two tabs at the bottom and a round button in the middle in front of these tabs, and a fragment that in the image is the blue background.

So I can make the tabs and the fragment just fine. but how can I put the round button in front of the tabs and the fragment?

Check [this](http://s28.postimg.org/9ghqa4iyl/1781529_10203086496259328_1541074271_n.jpg) image

thanks

Comment: How about using this? - https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

Comment: not what I need. but thanks

Comment: Well you could use a small circular layout and make it clickable.

Comment: Use a `RelativeLayout` so you can add views on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
   android:layout_width="200dp"/>

   <Button
   android:text="Frame"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now button is in front of The Image.

Answer (score 0):

You can add layout_marginTop attribute to the view you would want to be in front of the Fragment. Example

```
  <ImageView 
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_width="200dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"/>
```

This will move the ImageView 100dp upwards in front of the Fragment. Hope it helps